# How to access value in req.body after AJAX Post on server side using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, req

I'm using AJAX to post JSON:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true})); 

const rowObject=JSON.stringify(rowData)
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/api/entities/liquid',
            data: rowObject,
            dataType: 'application/json',
          
            success: function(){
            //success code here
            },
            error: function(){
            //error code here
            }
            });

      return rowObject
```

When I console.log(req.body), it returns the following:

```
{
  '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"...}': ''
}
```

I should be able to extract value1 by using req.body.value1 but it's always undefined.  The client side shows a payload of `[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]:` in an Array[0] I'm getting a 400 response but I know that's because I'm not able to extract the values. I've tried req.query, req.params and also tried to add the index of the array like req.body[0].key1 - still undefined. I'm a novice so this may be just a basic js issue but I don't understand why extracting the value is so complicated. I have another form that works fine using the data[0].value1 format.  I tried using "data" as well and it's not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

If You Are Using express.json() middleware than just use req.body first console it and check it you are getting the the data or not.

PS: Please Provide More Info About question. And if you are using express version of 4 than you dont need to download body parser

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  When I console.log req.body I get the following:
{
  '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"...}': ''
}
So it's not undefined - but appears to be invalid. 
Express version is 4.18.2